# Spring cloud data flow kubernetes

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a basic question about deploying Spring tasks/batch jobs on SCDF Kubernetes. Now if I deploy the SCDF on Kubernetes and then schedule a batch job, which Kubernetes cluster is the batch job deployed on? where is the pod created? the same cluster where the SCDF server is running?

Answer (score 0):

By default the apps are deployed on the same cluster and namespace as the SCDF server but this is configurable. You can configure any number of target “platforms”. Each platform is essentially a set of deployment properties keyed to a logical name. You can set the platform name as a parameter on which each task is launched. This is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes-tasks)